# Angular 2 Infinite Scroll module this.scrollCallback is not a function

Tags: angular, angular2-services, infinite-scroll

Im trying to implement Angular Infinite Scroller with RxJS with the help of the below link.

https://github.com/ashwin-sureshkumar/angular-infinite-scroller

Alt Link:

https://codeburst.io/angular-2-simple-infinite-scroller-directive-with-rxjs-observables-a989b12d4fb1

Below is how i have integated into my project.

**UPDATED: File which the error log is pointing**

**app\components\layout\order-issue\infinite-scroller.directive.ts**

```
 private requestCallbackOnScroll() {
this.requestOnScroll$ = this.userScrolledDown$;

if (this.immediateCallback) {
  this.requestOnScroll$ = this.requestOnScroll$
    .startWith([DEFAULT_SCROLL_POSITION, DEFAULT_SCROLL_POSITION]);
}

this.requestOnScroll$
  .exhaustMap(() => {
    return this.scrollCallback();
  })
  .subscribe((data) => { console.log(data) }, (err) => console.log(err));
}
```

**app\components\layout\order-issue\order-issue.module.ts**

```
import { InfiniteScrollerDirective } from './infinite-scroller.directive';
...
declarations: [OrderIssueComponent,...],
```

**app\components\layout\order-issue\order-issue.component.ts**

```
import { InfiniteScrollerDirective } from './infinite-scroller.directive';
import { OrderService } from "../../../services/order.services";

export class OrderIssueComponent implements OnInit {

 currentPage: number = 1;
 news: Array<any> = [];
 scrollCallback;

constructor(private orderService: OrderService) {
      this.scrollCallback = this.getStories();
  }

 getStories() {
   console.log('Got stories...')
    return this.orderService.getAllOrders_infinite_scroll("Pending",this.currentPage).subscribe(this.processData);
  }

   private processData = (news) => {
    console.log("process data");
    this.news = news.Allorders.concat(news.Allorders);
    console.log(this.news);
   }
}
```

**UPDATED:**

**\app\services\order.services.ts**

```
 getAllOrders_infinite_scroll(status,page: number = 1): Observable<any> {  //updated line
    console.log('adadasd')
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post(`${BASE_URL}/orders/getAllOrdersWithItems`, { status: status }, { headers: headers })
   .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

**Problem here:**

**app\components\layout\order-issue\order-issue.component.html**

```
  <ul id="infinite-scroller" appInfiniteScroller scrollPerecnt="70" [immediateCallback]="true" [scrollCallback]="scrollCallback">
         <div *ngFor="let orders of news" class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
               <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                         <h4>{{news.Allorders.orderNo}}</h4>
                            <h6>{{news.Allorders.user_id.username}}</h6>
                    </div>
               </div>
               ....
          </div>
   </ul>
```

**UPDATED log:**  have put logs just to track the flow

[image]

I just dont get any view if i use 'orders of news'.

Tried with news.orderNo too

Below is the console error trace:

> TypeError: _this.scrollCallback is not a function
>       at SwitchFirstMapSubscriber.project (infinite-scroller.directive.ts:86)
>       at SwitchFirstMapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/exhaustMap.js.SwitchFirstMapSubscriber.tryNext (exhaustMap.js:93)
>       at SwitchFirstMapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/exhaustMap.js.SwitchFirstMapSubscriber._next (exhaustMap.js:86)
>       at SwitchFirstMapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
>       at MergeAllSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/OuterSubscriber.js.OuterSubscriber.notifyNext (OuterSubscriber.js:19)
>       at InnerSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/InnerSubscriber.js.InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:23)
>       at InnerSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
>       at Object.subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:17)

Comment: Can you help me with your angular version?

Comment: I m using Angular 4, have updated package.json

Answer (score 0):

in your `order.services.ts` > `getAllOrders_infinite_scroll` function you will need to return an observable if you don't return an observable than you won't be able to subscribe to it. Maybe that's why you're not receiving any callback.

Like this...

```
getAllOrders_infinite_scroll(status,page: number = 1): Observable<any> {
   // your code
  }
```

Also, this line would change as well

```
this.orderService.getAllOrders_infinite_scroll("Pending",this.currentPage).subscribe(res => this.processData = res);
```

One more tip a new HttpClient module has beed added as a part of update in Angular 4.3 by using that you won't need to `map(res => res.json())` anymore [more info here](https://angular.io/guide/http)

Comment: tried ur code...i still get same error stack trace as given in my question

Comment: Ok @stack200s, Sorry I misunderstood your approach, you won't need to change this line `this.orderService.getAllOrders_infinite_scroll("Pending",this.currentPage).subscribe(res => this.processData = res);` Just make the first change I suggested.

Comment: OK have updated the service file to return an Observable as suggested and also have updated my console log for specific functions...The error mentioned still persists after changes too..

Comment: Hey @Abhilash Rathod, any update or suggestions on this?

Comment: @stack200s That's all I could understand and won't be able to provide more insights on this.